# Googledocs alternative for small business

Tags: linux

We're presently using googledocs(word processing, spreadsheet and email) for everything. We'd like to move away from remotely hosted software. We have a large internal infrastructure to support this sort of thing so technical resources won't be an issue.

Are there any decent alternatives to googledocs that meet the following requirements?

Open-source
Local Hosted option
Collaboration/multi-user support
Word processing
Spreadsheet support
Privacy features
Importing/Exporting
Minimal installation footprint

I've been leaning towards a collaboration suite, however, I was also wondering if there is some way to collaborate within Openoffice? Thanks!

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you would like something that is offered as a hosted service but which has the "insurance" of also being deployable locally?

Comment: Yes sir. I've modified my question to reflect that. Sorry for the confusion. We would require this be deployable locally/our own infrastructure.

Comment: Just how large is this business (how many people)? The title says "small business", yet the body tells us you have a large internal support infrastructure, which is inconsistent with a small business. The size may well matter when others are considering offering suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Zimbra (http://www.zimbra.com) is a great collaboration suite that have a local installable open Source edition and you can have eMail, Calendar and Documents on a local server.

Comment: Zimbra looks promising, but what are the installation footprint and privacy components? Edit: Have you personally used it? I ask because I'm familiar with it, as far as knowing it exists but I want some anecdotal experience in regards to using the suite if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Office Live is another option you may want to consider.
Any specifics to the reason why your not interested in staying with Google for these services?

In addition another option might be a managed hosting provider, building out a remote system with either citrix or ms terminal services.

Comment: Nick O'Neil, this is a Linux environment. Office live would not be a viable alternative. We're shying away from Googledocs due to privacy concerns and to demonstrate the capabilities of our infrastructure. I.e., use it to demonstrate that if its good enough for us, its good enough for our clients :)

Comment: Ahh yes, I should have noticed that with the mention of Openoffice I agree there are some concerns and potential compliance issues if there are sensitive pieces of client data on googledocs. Take a look at Logicworks, infiniCloud, this might not be exactly what you are looking for , but you never know.   I just checked out your site, looks like a really cool product.

Comment: Nick O'Neil, we are a cloud storage provider :) We want to deploy this to our own systems and have access to similar functionality as that offered by googledocs. With the added security of hosting it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[O3 spaces](http://www.o3spaces.com) offers both hosted and on-site plans:

http://www.o3spaces.com/Subscriptions___Licensing

It also has an open office extension.
http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/2

Comment: That doesn't look open-source...

Comment: yeah I guess you're right, although it does seem open source friendly enough.